# Capture color when running subprocess.run

Tags: python, colors, subprocess

If I do:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ touch foo/__init__.py
```

And then run

```
$ mypy foo             
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

then "Success: no issues found in 1 source file" is coloured green.

However, if I make a file `t.py` with

```py
import subprocess

output = subprocess.run(['mypy', 'foo'], text=True, capture_output=True)
print(output)
```

and run it:

```
$ python t.py
CompletedProcess(args=['mypy', 'foo'], returncode=0, stdout='Success: no issues found in 1 source file\n', stderr='')
```

then `stdout` only contains the message - the color is gone, and so is any hope of reconstructing it.

So, how could I run `mypy foo` from within `t.py` in such a way that I can get the color from `stdout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR

```py
import subprocess, os
my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env['MYPY_FORCE_COLOR'] = '1'

output = subprocess.run(['mypy', 'foo'], text=True, capture_output=True, env=my_env);
print(output.stdout)
```

First, it's normal that most of the console programs output data without colors if they think they haven't been run in interactive mode.
So, we need to force it to do so.

> There is an undocumented environment variable `MYPY_FORCE_COLOR` that
> will force color. ([source](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7771#issuecomment-544763442))

Till now, mypy doesn't have a documented command line option to do so, but we can use this hack. **Beware that this behavior may change some day!**

Code:

```py
# ...
import os
my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env['MYPY_FORCE_COLOR'] = '1'

# Set modified env
subprocess.run(..., env=my_env);
# ...
```

Then, print actual stdout to see ANSI escape codes (that is, colors).

```py
print(output.stdout)
```